# React Components Not Rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I can't even get my root app component to render.  I load localhost and it loads index.html successfully with no js errors but nothing is rendered to the page.  I can't pinpoint the problem if there are no errors :).  I looked at my code and I don't know what the deal is.  I'm new to React so...could be a bunch of issues below, I don't know.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.set("view options", {layout: false});
app.use(express.static('.'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="ink-grid vertical-space">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="panel vertical-space">
                    <div id="app"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from 'src/components/App';

const app = document.getElementById('app');
render(<App/>, app);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CompanyList from 'src/components/CompanyList';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="companyList">
                <CompanyList />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

**CompanyList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CompanyList extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h3>No Companies Found</h3>
        );
    }
}
export default CompanyList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the `type="text/babel"` on you're script tag. This type was intended to use with the now deprecated [babel browser](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/) to transpile ES6 and JSX in the browser.

You have to change the type to "text/javascript" to run the file. However, as the browser doesn't understand JSX, and some parts of ES6, this will mainly throw errors.

What you'll have to do in addition to make it work, is to use a build system, such as webpack, to transpile ES6 and JSX using babel, and bundle you're files, to something the browser can use. Try this [guide](http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/).

If you just want to practice react without the hassle of a build system, you can use the [React Base Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VovanR/0ggv6wnp/).

Comment: but I should able to do this without a build still somehow

Comment: I'm going to be using browserify at first then move to webpack later..but I'll read that post

Comment: You'll have to use babel to transpile you're code either in webpack or browserify. Webpack is a bit easier to use.

Comment: lol some could debate the "webpack is easier"...maybe for transpiling but everyone else has found it a pain to figure out at first and get your head wrapped around the gigantic beast of a config framework.